# Ajax call type POST showing undefined index error

Tags: javascript

I have a table where I'm displaying files uploaded

Comment: Change this line: `$deleteLink = '<a href="javascript:confirmDeletion(\"$key\")">Delete</a>';` your quotes were getting tangled up there and you had periods where they aren't needed

Comment: and in `function deleteFileRow(key)`.. change `type: "post",` and `data: { key: key},` - now you'll have a `$_POST['key']` in your PHP (_poet & I knowit_)

Comment: @Kinglish it says "attribute $key is not allowed here" when I do that. Not sure if my formatting is the best way to write it but it's working and doesn't show an error

Comment: @Kinglish yea I just did that from AidOnline01 's answer and that works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem (where the server does not handle a proper request as expected), or a Javascript problem (where the request isn't sent properly)?

Comment: @Kinglish Hey so I actually changed this line `$deleteLink = '<a href="javascript:confirmDeletion('.$key.')">Delete</a>'` to this `$deleteLink = '<a href="javascript:confirmDeletion(\"$splits[1]"\)">Delete</a>'` but I get a syntax error that says Unexpected end of input and just shows `confirmDeletion(`. Since there's an escape string, I think it's not detecting the part after.

Comment: `$deleteLink = '<a href="javascript:confirmDeletion("' . $splits[1] .'")">Delete</a>';` - try that

Comment: @Kinglish that also shows the same thing as before

Comment: sounds like there isn't a index 1 on $splits. Why not just use $key?

Comment: @Kinglish there is, it shows up when I do inspect code, but it looks like this: `<a href="javascript:confirmDeletion(" filedrop129379.23")">Delete</a>`. I made some changes to the code so I don't need the key anymore, just that file name. I think the formatting is being difficult because I'm using `$deleteLink` as a parameter to call `displayDeleteInRow()`.

Comment: `$deleteLink = '<a href="javascript:confirmDeletion(\'{$splits[1]}\')">Delete</a>';` -- quote escaping from php to javascript can be tricky

Comment: @Kinglish yea still no luck :( it says `missing ) after argument list`

Comment: argh!! because its wrapped in single quotes which will not parse php. `$deleteLink = "<a href='javascript:confirmDeletion(\"{$splits[1]}\")'>Delete</a>";`

Comment: @Kinglish ohhhh. I am still getting the `missing ) after argument list` but I think we are getting closer. This is wat it shows when I click on that error: `displayDeleteInRow('<a href='javascript:confirmDeletion("FileDrop1623719182.5038")'>Delete</a>', '1')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are need to pass object to data, not int/string. So the code will be

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {key: key}
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data .

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'abc.php',
    data: {"key":"value"},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.value1);
    }
 });
```